# Getting sensitivity and specificity from a caret model

Tags: r, caret, model-evaluation

I have trained a caret model using bootstrapping and the default metric (accuracy, since I'm doing logistic regression). Now I'd like to know other performance parameters for the trained model: sensitivity, specificity, ROC etc. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`confusionMatrix()` gives you all that you need probably.

You need to pass two `factor` vectors, one with the predictions and one with the truth (reference). As you can read here [?confusionMatrix](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/confusionMatrix).

You can access each element, otherwise you can use functions like `negPredValue()` to get *sensitivity* or *specificity* alone. (refer to [?negPredValue](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/negPredValue) for more info)

For the ROC curve I suggest the package `pROC` and the function `roc()`.
It also gives you the Area Under the Curve with `auc()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the `confusionMatrix()` to an object you can then subset it easily with `$` or `[]`. So for example:

```
confmat <- confusionMatrix(y, preds)

confmat$byClass[, "Sensitivity"]
```

That just outputs a named numeric vector, so you can operate on it easily (e.g. by using `mean()` to get the average). If you just do `confmat$byClass` you can see the other performance metrics available.